# Getting a a Fatal Signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 using Realm

Tags: android, realm

It seems this error is caused by bugs in native code, and that this is due to the `Realm` library -- based on seeing the phrase `librealm-jni.so` in the "Build Fingerprint" beneath the error. I have the latest version of `Realm` installed -- 1.2.0.

Here's the error code:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14c in tid 7837 (ator.app)
```

Here's the "Build Fingerprint:"

```
    Build fingerprint: 'generic/vbox86p/vbox86p:5.0/LRX21M/buildbot11172321:userdebug/test-keys'
26643-26643/? I/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
26643-26643/? I/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86'
26643-26643/? I/DEBUG: pid: 7837, tid: 7837, name: ator.app  >>> com.lockedout.app <<<
26643-26643/? I/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x14c
26643-26643/? I/DEBUG:     eax 00000148  ebx ffffffff  ecx 7470d340  edx 00000002
26643-26643/? I/DEBUG:     esi 00000000  edi 00000002
26643-26643/? I/DEBUG:     xcs 00000023  xds 0000002b  xes 0000002b  xfs 00000007  xss 0000002b
26643-26643/? I/DEBUG:     eip e2f6d025  ebp ffd3cd58  esp ffd3cd50  flags 00210246
26643-26643/? I/DEBUG: backtrace:
26643-26643/? I/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0002a025  /data/app/com.lockedout.app-1/lib/x86/librealm-jni.so
26643-26643/? I/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0009c141  /data/app/com.lockedout.app-1/lib/x86/librealm-jni.so
26643-26643/? I/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0009c299  /data/app/com.lockedout.app-1/lib/x86/librealm-jni.so
26643-26643/? I/DEBUG:     #03 pc 004002d3  /data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.lockedout.app-1@base.apk@classes.dex
26643-26643/? I/DEBUG:     #04 pc 00000002  <unknown>
26643-26643/? I/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_06
```

### Update:

I narrowed down the problem to happening after I call `notifyDataSetChanged` on my `RecyclerView.Adapter`, but my code doesn't do anything else after that executes. So I narrowed down the problem area even further to line 135 in android's `Looper` class:

```
Message msg = queue.next(); // might block
```

I'm not sure what this means, but I imagine someone who knows the internals of `Realm` may be able to shed some insight on why the error is being caused in `Looper`.

Some more information about the changes that occured in `Realm` before the error:
`notifyDataSetChanged` is triggered inside of a `RealmChangeListener` set on a `RealmObject` aka "User". The transaction that caused the change deleted a custom `RealmObject` aka "Item" from `User`'s `RealmList<Item>`. I know for a fact that that is the only transaction and operation that occurs because of my code. Here is the code that deletes the `Item`:

```
RealmSingleton.getUserInstance().executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        UserSingleton.getUser().deleteItem(mItem.getClassId());
    }
});
```

### Update:

The exact line of Realm code that causes the error is line 149 in `SharedGroup`:

```
148    void commitAndContinueAsRead() {
149            nativeCommitAndContinueAsRead(nativePtr);
150    }
```

Comment: We'd need to know what thread this method is called on, and what UserSingleton.getUser() is, what thread it is on, when it is updated, and if by chance you do any synchronous transactions on the UI thread, and in worst case scenario if you use synchronous transaction in a RealmChangeListener.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce method is called from a callback in an `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute`, so i think that would mean it is called from the ui thread. `UserSingleton.getUser` is a `RealmObject` on the ui thread. all of my transactions are synchronous on every thread, and no transactions are done at all in any `RealmChangeListeners`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce the reason i use only synchronous transactions is because when i started doing transactions with `Transactions` i used asynchronous transactions and there were bugs, but when i switched to using synchronous transactions everything seemed to be fixed -- this is all on the ui thread.

Comment: Did `doInBackground()` modify the `User` table?

Comment: no, it's just a timer that doesn't execute anything until `onPostExecute`

Comment: ....okay now I'm getting curious, can you share the code for this AsyncTask? and even more importantly, **are you using async queries** ? (I'd probably have to see more of the code to tell what breaks, which means you might have to send this case over to `help[at]realm.io` )

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i misspoke. the method is not run in AsyncTask's onPostExecute. that's the method that posts changes to the server. the Realm transaction is just run in a plain old method in a RecyclerView.ViewHolder. and no, i'm not using async queries. i remember you telling me that before, and i did it, but my app was crashing, so i ended up making all the transactions synchronous and it fixed the problem.

Comment: why is this emphasis on using async queries not in the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

(I am still not an official Realm person)

**Note:** In order to actually answer this question, I'd have to see the full code. After all, Realm handles most possible crashes on the native side and throw it as an exception to Java, so you're probably doing something very wrong. :P

**Guesses:**

1.) you're using asynchronous queries combined with synchronous write on the UI thread, thus [creating detached row accessors that you then try to delete based on ID despite it not being its latest version](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2976).

(Asynchronous queries aren't immediately executed, you need to listen to its completion using `RealmChangeListener`, but if you mix them with synchronous writes on the UI thread, you force the query to become synchronous.)

2.) You modified something on a background thread which has not yet updated the RealmResults on the UI thread (running the event handling with the looper), and the element you're trying to use in the transaction is not up to date, so its deletion crashes.

**Possible solutions:**

a.) Use `executeTransactionAsync()` instead of `executeTransaction()` when you're on the UI thread.

b.) In your method

```
UserSingleton.getUser().deleteItem(mItem.getClassId());
```

Not sure what `UserSingleton` is, but before you delete an element, you should consider requerying it based on ID inside the transaction to obtain the latest version of the element (which is potentially not updated yet in this particular case, synchronous transaction on the UI thread, after all)

**Possible course of action:**

If you want to help out Realm, if this crash is reproducible, consider sending the project over to `help[at]realm.io` so that they can look at it and fix it up. After all, you should get Java exceptions, not native crashes.

Comment: ok. i found the exact line of Realm code that causes the error. it's `nativeCommitAndContinueAsRead(nativePtr);` -- line 149 in `SharedGroup`.

Comment: Clearly if I knew more of your code, I'd be able to tell why the versioning of your object fails and points to somewhere when it shouldn't in the transaction. Nice find by the way, you broke Realm in a way that no one else has before :D you should send a sample to help at realm.io